# Parsing arguments for cd command

Tags: c++, parsing, linux

This [file manager](https://github.com/corporateshark/WalCommander) has a code snippet that handles an argument of the "cd" console command. It converts the argument to a valid path, expands ~ and environment variables into the corresponding values:

```
std::vector<unicode_t> ConvertCDArgToPath( const unicode_t* p )
{
    std::vector<unicode_t> Out;

    std::vector<unicode_t> Temp;

    while ( p && *p )
    {
        unicode_t Ch = 0;

        if ( *p == '~' )
        {
            if ( LookAhead( p, &Ch ) )
            {
                if ( ( IsPathSeparator(Ch) || Ch == 0 ) && ApplyEnvVariable( "HOME", &Temp ) )
                {
                    // replace ~ with the HOME path
                    Out.insert( Out.end(), Temp.begin(), Temp.end() );
                    PopLastNull( &Out );
                }
            }
        }
        else if ( *p == '$' )
        {
            // skip `$`
            std::vector<char> EnvVarName = unicode_to_utf8( p+1 );
            for ( auto i = EnvVarName.begin(); i != EnvVarName.end(); i++ )
            {
                if ( IsPathSeparator( *i ) )
                {
                    *i = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if ( ApplyEnvVariable( EnvVarName.data( ), &Temp ) )
            {
                // replace the var name with its value
                Out.insert( Out.end(), Temp.begin(), Temp.end() );
                PopLastNull( &Out );
                // skip var name
                p += strlen( EnvVarName.data() );
            }
        }
        else if ( IsPathSeparator(*p) )
        {
            if ( !LastCharEquals( Out, '/' ) && !LastCharEquals( Out, '\\' ) ) Out.push_back( DIR_SPLITTER );
        }
        else
        {
            Out.push_back( *p );
        }
        p++;
    }

    Out.push_back( 0 );

    return Out;
}

bool LookAhead( const unicode_t* p, unicode_t* OutNextChar )
{
    if ( !p ) return false;
    if ( !*p ) return false;
    if ( OutNextChar ) *OutNextChar = *(p+1);
    return true;
}
```

1. Is this code secure?
2. What is missing?
3. How can I deal with the duplicate code around the `ApplyEnvVariable()` calls?

Comment: Isn't `~` expanded by the shell automatically when used as parameter?

Comment: This code is not for the shell. The file manager handles the ``cd`` command internally to switch to the desired folder. I.e. ``cd ~/Projects/$PROJNAME/data`` should work.

Comment: @SergeyK. most shells already do all this for you why are you trying to do it inside the command?

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask this question: `Is this code secure?`

Comment: @LokiAstari: will it allow me to read back the result of the command? The path to the resulting folder.

Answer (score 2):

**What is missing**

A compatibility with existing shells. There are certain expectations on how the expansion works; your code expands in an incompatible way; expect end-user complains:

- Tilde is expanded only in the beginning of the word. You expand it anywhere.
- Tilde may be followed by a login name, then the whole prefix is expanded to a home directory of *that* user. You do not expand the tilde-prefix.
- There is no provision to escape tilde or `$` from expanding.
- There is no way to limit variable name before it hits the path separator.

**How to deal with the duplicate code around `ApplyEnvVariable()` calls**

I guess, the simplest way is to move the duplicated code directly into `ApplyEnvVariable()`. That would actually justify the name of the method: as of now it doesn't *apply* the variable but merely *expands* it.  Of course you'd need to pass `Out.end()` instead of `Temp` there.

**Naming**

It is very unusual to have variable names capitalized.

Comment: Nice list of compatibility issues!